# Find which array entry is contained in specific string in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a string that I know will contain one entry from an array of strings. I'm looking for which array entry the string contains.

If I have the following variables:

```
$String = "This is my string"
$Array = "oh","my","goodness"
```

I can verify *if* any of the array entries exist in the string with:

```
$String -match $($Array -join "|")
```

But, this will only return true or false. I want to know which entry was matched.

-Contains seems to be going in the right direction, but that only verifies if an array contains a specific object, and I want to verify which of the array entries is contained within the string. I'm thinking something like a foreach loop would do the trick, but that seems like a fairly resource intensive workaround.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the automatic variable `$Matches` is for.

See [about_Regular_Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1#groups-captures-and-substitutions)

```
$String = "This is my string"
$Array = "oh","my","goodness"

if($String -match $($Array -join "|"))
{
    $Matches
}
```

Returns:

```
PS /> 

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              my
```

This is another way you can see the matches:

```
# Adding "This" for the example

$String = "This is my string"
[regex]$Array = "oh","my","goodness","This" -join '|'

$Array.Matches($String)
```

Returns:

```
PS />

Groups Success Name Captures Index Length Value
------ ------- ---- -------- ----- ------ -----
{0}       True 0    {0}          0      4 This
{0}       True 0    {0}          8      2 my
```